# Getting size of pdf without downloading

Tags: python, http-headers, request

Is it possible to know the size of a pdf e.g. http://example.com/ABC.pdf using requests module in python without actually downloading it.
I am writing an application where if the internet speed is slow and if the size of the pdf is large then it will postpone the download for the future

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## use a HTTP-HEAD request

Response shall provide in headers more details of the file to download without fetching full file.

```
>>> url = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf"
>>> req = requests.head(url)
>>> req.content
''
>>> req.headers["content-length"]
'433994'
```

## or try streaming read

```
>>> req = requests.get(url, stream=True)
>>> res = req.iter_content(30)
>>> res
<generator object generate at 0x7f9ad3270320>
>>> res.next()
'%PDF-1.3\n%\xc7\xec\x8f\xa2\n30 0 obj\n<</Len'
>>> res.next()
'gth 31 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode'
>>> res.next()
'>>\nstream\nx\x9c\xed}\xdd\x93%\xb7m\xef\xfb\xfc\x15S\xf7%NU\xf6\xb8'
```

You can then decode pdf size from initial pdf file bytes and decide to continue or not.

## Use Range request header

HTTP allows asking for retrieval only range of bytes.

If your server supports that, you can use a trick, you ask for range of bytes which are available only with too large files. If you get some bytes (and status is OK), you know, the file is too large.

If you get an exception `ChunkedEncodingError: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)`, then you know, the file is smaller.

Call it like this:

```
>>> headers = {"Range": "bytes=999500-999600"}
>>> req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This will work only, if your server allows serving partial content.

Comment: The pdf files that I am downloading do not have any "content-length" key in headers. In one of the questions regarding .jpg files I read that you could read the first 24 or 50 bytes and determine the size. Can a similar method be followed in case of pdf file

Comment: In such case, you shall use `stream` parameter at your request (get, post, whatever return the pdf).

Comment: @bhavesh Added the streaming solution. I did not investigate, how to determine PDF size from it's initial bytes, but it shall not be so difficult to find it out.

Answer (score 7):

Like this

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com/ABC.pdf')
size_of_pdf = response.headers['Content-Length']
```

Before `response.read()` is called, the contents are not downloaded.

Take a look at `Response Headers` in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_Headers)

```
...
Content-Length  The length of the response body in octets (8-bit bytes) Content-Length: 348 Permanent
...
```

OP asked for using `requests`, so @JanVlcinsky answer is more appropriate.

Comment: Just a note: OP asked for using `requests` module.